# How to determine parameters for native apps for deep linking on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, parameter-passing, url-scheme, deep-linking

I am still new to custom URLs and deep linking, but I have not been able to find answers to what I'm looking for on other stackoverflow Q/As.

The context of my question is Android and iOS. My app is HTML5 in Sencha Touch, and uses plugins for native calls. So I need to figure this out for Android and iOS.

Here's the problem. Say I have a a document ID for an Evernote note, and I want my app to launch the Evernote app (assuming it's installed) and have that document open up, then how do I go about doing that? Specifically, how do I know what parameters and parameter names I need to pass to Evernote? Is there a way to "inspect" the Evernote app or do I need to get some official documentation from Evernote about what parameter names/values I can provide?

In my example above, we can replace that with something else as well. Say I have a file "doc.xls" that is in Google Drive. Assuming I have Google Drive app installed, how can I open the Google Drive app with "doc.xls" opened? How do I determine what parameters I need to (or can) pass while opening a native app?

I understand the idea of opening and launching other native apps; I have seen examples for Android and iOS but I cannot figure out how to determine the parameters - which is what my question is about.

Is there some general reading I should do on some particular topic to figure this out? Let me know if I can clarify anything about my question.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Mohammad
San Jose, CA

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial by sencha team 
On the use of Custom Scheme URLs to launch App

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.device.Device

you may also try the phonegap version.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

all the best Hope this is not too late..